# RabbitMQ HA: Mirroring VS Pacemaker

Tags: rabbitmq

1 - Could anyone elaborate on the differences between these two approaches?
2 - In details what happens to queues and messages if one node fails in each approach?

I see in the docs

> Whilst RabbitMQ also supports clustering, clustering is intended to facilitate scalability, not availability. Thus in a cluster, if a node fails, queues which were on the failed node are lost. With the high availability setup described in this guide, when a node fails, the durable queues and the persistent messages within them can be recovered by a different node.

Does this apply to mirrored queues?

Answer (score 1):

Mirrored queues, [as described on the RabbitMQ website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html), mean all messages are replicated on all nodes configured to host slave queues. Once a message reaches a mirrored queue, you won't loose it in case of a node failure.

A mirrored queue is implemented with "copies" of it on all configured nodes. One of these copies is the queue master (initially located on the node where the queue was created by default). The other copies are queue slaves.

Your clients can connect and interact with this queue from any nodes in the clustered (even nodes which don't hold the master or a slave).

To guarantee messages ordering, all messages go through the queue master first, then are replicated on all slaves. This means there might be a lot of inter-node communication.

When a node fails, if this node held a queue master, one of the queue slaves is elected as the new master. When the node comes back, it now holds a queue slave.